# Specific workstation loses ability to communicate with specific server

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection

Our team has SQL Server databases on two separate hosts (test and prod) provided by corporate IT.

Working on and running a tool that does a lot of database-oriented work from my Windows 7 machine, I am suddenly unable to connect to the test database or test database host after a period of interaction.

What I mean is that I will suddenly get errors in logs:

> ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper // The connection to the host
>   TESTHOST, named instance TEST failed. Error:
>   "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the
>   server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP
>   traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the
>   SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

I am unable to ping `TESTHOST` ("General Failure" is the only error message displayed) nor telnet (to 1979) nor tracert (also "General Failure" - immediately).

While this is happening, I can ping, tracert, telnet as well as connect using SQL Server Management Studio to the `PRODHOST/PROD` database instance without a problem. Other people on my team can connect to `TESTHOST\TEST` just fine during this 'blackout period' for me. After a period of time (without even restarting my PC) I can resume connecting to test both via telnet and via SQL Server Management Studio or the tool itself.

Windows Firewall is disabled by IT. There is a McAfee Agent installed as well as McAfee Virus Security. I can't do anything about those. Any more "it don't work!" to IT and I'm just going to have my machine re-imaged and that wont even necessarily fix it (objections to not bothering to understand root cause notwithstanding), but it will obstruct me from working on any number of other things that aren't being impacted by this one particular tool not being able to be further developed.

I'm perplexed: I am not a very super user, but can anyone help me even start investigating what is happening? The evidence suggests, to me, that this is an issue with my system exclusively (so, maybe a re-image would be fine).  I've tried random things like installing the newest drivers for my Intel 82578DM Gigabit Network Adapter, disabling IPv6, as well as `netsh int ip reset` (which did not allow me to start connecting again, only time or a reset does).

Comment: I will not jump to conclusion/suggestion about driver or hardware issue for now, as you can access other machines when this happen. (1) Does this always happen when you doing the same task? (2) Is/Are the task very heavy in terms of network traffic? (3) Do you have access to TESTHOST event log? That may provide hint.

Comment: Yes, it happens when I do the same task (though that is rather high level, it's running a tool that reads data from a database, performs some external calculations, then attempts to write new rows to another table). It has always happened during a select (but the selects also outweigh the inserts)  I wouldn't say that it is a large amount of traffic - just a consistent number of say, 3-5 queries per second. I've requested the event log.

Comment: I kind of feel the server(TESTHOST) is shuting your machine out for some reason. But we will wait for the event log.

Comment: So this tool runs inside TomEE - I just copied the TomEE installation as well as the WAR to another machine and it is running fine.

Comment: What about the jre? Are they the same version?

Comment: When the machine is connecting normally, can your machine ping the server? If no, I think there is a firewall on the server. Additionally, is this realated to named instant? Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10392038/1810391

Comment: My machine is running 1.7.0_07-b10 JRE and the other machine is 1.7.0-b147

Comment: I can connect to the TESTHOST just fine - I can even connect to TESTHOST/TEST named instance, execute SQL queries and what have you. It's only after the tool has run for a few minutes and been issuing 3-5 queries per second that it will suddenly be unable to connect (and all subsequent attempts to communicate with the HOST, not just the database fail).

Comment: (1) Check event log on your machine, focus on time around the problem happen. (2) Possible to use the same JRE on your machine? That should at least eliminate one factor.